# Java web service not giving error message

Tags: java, web-services, soap

I am doing a simple Hello World example of java webservices, which is of document style from this [link](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/jax-ws-hello-world-example-document-style/), he told that at step Number 3 , we will get an error message "Wrapper class com.mkyong.ws.jaxws.GetHelloWorldAsString is not found. 
    Have you run APT to generate them?".
But with out using wsgen, I am able to run my application with out any exception and able to see the output at client end. I am unable to find the reason , why didn't I get the error message?
Here is my code:
HelloWorld.java :

```
   package com.XXX.ws;

import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding.Style;

@WebService
@SOAPBinding(style = Style.DOCUMENT,use=Use.LITERAL)
public interface HelloWorld {

    @WebMethod String getHelloWorldAsString(String name);
}
```

HelloWorldImpl.java:

```
package com.XXX.ws;

import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebService;
@WebService(endpointInterface = "com.XXX.ws.HelloWorld")
public class HelloWorldImpl implements HelloWorld {

    @Override
    public String getHelloWorldAsString(String name) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return "Hello"+name;
    }

}
```

Publisher.java

```
package com.XXX.endOP;

import javax.xml.ws.Endpoint;

import com.XXX.ws.HelloWorldImpl;

public class EndPublisher {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Endpoint.publish("http://localhost:9999/ws/hello", new HelloWorldImpl());
        System.out.println("Started");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After so much search found the following line

> Using javac with JAX-WS annotation processor will generates the
>   portable artifacts used in JAX-WS services.
>   from this link
>   https://jax-ws.java.net/nonav/2.2.6/docs/ch04.html