# Jax-ws endpoint not asking to create wrapper classes

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, soap, jax-ws

I'm following this simple tutorial:  https://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/jax-ws-hello-world-example-document-style/?fbclid=IwAR0vxhYrj9MKy1Q28h6luFVJoSxDP4KWBOLEu_v_Ss4uQztmB-9JuYsS4RI and at step 3 it mentions that I should receive the error:

```
Wrapper class com.mkyong.ws.jaxws.GetHelloWorldAsString is not found. 
Have you run APT to generate them?
```

However, I do not get such error(no error at all) and I'm worried that it is not working as expected.
My classes:

Interface:

```
package com.soap3sk.ws;

import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding.Style;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding.Use;

// Service Endpoint Interface
@WebService
@SOAPBinding(style= Style.DOCUMENT, use= Use.LITERAL) // optional
public interface NoteEndpoint {
    //@WebMethod ArrayList<ToDoNote> getNotes();
    @WebMethod String getHelloWorldAsString(String name);
}
```

Implementation:

```
package com.soap3sk.ws;

import javax.jws.WebService;

@WebService(endpointInterface = "com.soap3sk.ws.NoteEndpoint")
public class NoteEndpointImpl implements NoteEndpoint {

    @Override
    public String getHelloWorldAsString(String name) {
        return "Hello World JAX-WS " + name;
    }


}
```

Publisher:

```
package com.soap3sk.endpoint;

import javax.xml.ws.Endpoint;

import com.soap3sk.ws.NoteEndpointImpl;



public class NoteEndpointPublisher {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
    Endpoint.publish("http://localhost:5000/ws/hello", new NoteEndpointImpl());
}
}
```

Project structure: https://imagizer.imageshack.com/img924/3514/BAuOcl.png

What I also noticed that those 2 .class files(asString and Response that are mentioned in the guide) are not generated anywhere as well. I'm using Eclipse and created a maven project with the quickstart archetype. Runnning it as a standard java application.

I can access the wsdl file going here: http://localhost:5000/ws/hello?wsdl and the I can see getHelloWorldAsString and getHelloWorldAsStringResponse there, but they are nowhere to be seen in my project and no error is thrown that they could not be found as mentioned in the guide that it should.

I also tried downloading the sample project and deleting the .java files that should be required, but it is stil the same(no error, not asking to create those classes).

I would be very grateful if someone could help. Thank you.

**EDIT**
I found a similiar question here: [Java web service not giving error message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35985092/java-web-service-not-giving-error-message) Could someone explain his answer? Is the creation of those two classes not necessary?

Answer (score 0):

you're trying to replicate a situation reported almost 10 years ago. Don't you want to try a newer tutorial like the following:

- https://www.baeldung.com/jax-ws
- https://spring.io/guides/gs/producing-web-service/

Comment: I would prefer using Jax-WS (preferably with the document literal approach). Also, If you know what methods there are to access an existing Rest service within the Soap web service, but give responses and request to the Soap web service.(You could call it like a wrapper arround the RestService using Soap). Lastly, I believe that there is no issue with the older tutorial itself. The biggest problem I see is those two .class files not being generated for some reason.